# Pagination in requestAction

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.4

I'm building a dynamic view (`Page`) that consists of multiple elements (widgets) called via `$this->element('messages_unread')`. Some of these elements need data that is **not** related to the Page model.
In real life words: my users will be able to construct their own Page by choosing from a multitude of elements ("top 5 posts", "10 unread messages", etc...)

I get the data by calling `$this->requestAction(array('controller'=>'events','action'=>'archive')` from within the element, the url-variables differ per element .

I'm aware of the fact that `requestAction()` is expensive and I plan on limiting the costs by proper caching.

**The actual question:**
My problem is Pagination. When I'm in the `Page` view and call `requestAction('/events/archive')` the PaginatorHelper in the Page view will be unaware of the `Event` model and its paginator variables and `$this->Paginator->next()` etc... will not work.
How can I implement proper Pagination? I've tried to set the model by calling `$this->Paginator->options(array('model'=>'Event'))` but that doesn't work.
Do I maybe need to return custom defined Pagination variables in the `requestAction` and thus construct my own?

Or is there another approach that maybe even avoids `requestAction()`? And keep in mind here that the requested data is unrelated to the Page.

Kind regards,
Bart

**[Edit] My temporary solution but still open for comments/solutions:**
In the requestedAction `Event/archive`, return paginator variables along with the data like this:
`return array('data'=>$this->paginate(), 'paging' => $this->params['paging']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tinkered a bit more and the following works for me, and the PaginationHelper works:

In the element:

```
// requestAction returns an array('data'=>... , 'paging'=>...)
$data = $this->requestAction(array('controller'=>'events','action'=>'archive'));  

// if the 'paging' variable is populated, merge it with the already present paging variable in $this->params. This will make sure the PaginatorHelper works
if(!isset($this->params['paging'])) $this->params['paging'] = array();
$this->params['paging'] = array_merge( $this->params['paging'] , $data['paging'] );

foreach($data['events'] as $event) {
    // loop through data...
}
```

In the Controller:

```
public function archive() {
    $this->paginate = array(
        'limit'     => 10
    );

    if ($this->params['requested'])
        return array('events'=>$this->paginate('Event'), 'paging' => $this->params['paging']);

    $this->set('events', $this->paginate('Event') );
}
```